# How can i Get My Solution by using Group by and Joins

Tags: postgresql-9.2

**In POSTGRESql::**

I have a **TableA** with Columns

```
id  |   descr     |  team      |  status
254 | NSWemp      | Sales      | A
365 | NSW,VIC emp | Sales      | L
345 | NSW emp     | Post Sales | A
```

I have a **TableB** with Columns

```
id   | state
254  | NSW
365  | NSW
365  | VIC
365  | QLD
2345 | NT
2345 | NSW
```

**My Requirement** :: Is there any way of getting the output as ::

```
id     |    descr    |  team       |   status  |    state
254    | NSWemp      | Sales       | A         | NSW
365    | NSW,VIC emp | Sales       | L         | NSW,VIC,QLD
2345   | NSW emp     | Post Sales  | A         | NT,NSW
```

I had tried with JOINS and GROUP BY, But i cant make it work! Any suggestions for it to Work ?

```
SELECT TABLEA.ID,DESCR,TEAM,STATUS,STATE 
     FROM TABLEA 
     inner join TABLEB   ON TABLEA.ID = TABLEB.ID 
   GROUP BY  TABLEA.ID,DESCR,TEAM,STATUS,TABLEB.STATE;

      id  |    descr    |    team    | status | state
    ------+-------------+------------+--------+-------
     2345 | NSW emp     | Post Sales | A      | NT
      365 | NSW,VIC emp | Sales      | L      | NSW
      254 | NSWemp      | Sales      | A      | NSW
     2345 | NSW emp     | Post Sales | A      | NSW
      365 | NSW,VIC emp | Sales      | L      | QLD
      365 | NSW,VIC emp | Sales      | L      | VIC

(6 rows)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [ARRAY_AGG()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-aggregate.html)

```
SELECT TABLEA.ID,
       DESCR,
       TEAM,
       STATUS,
       array_agg(STATE) 
       FROM TABLEA 
        inner join TABLEB
          ON TABLEA.ID = TABLEB.ID 
       GROUP BY TABLEA.ID,DESCR,TEAM,STATUS
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/fe647/1)

Comment: My account is kept blocked ! i dont knew y is my account is been blocked !! how can i unblock my account back...@valex